# Powershell script to delete oldest files when free space is lower than 5gb

Tags: powershell-3.0, diskspace

I'm trying to create a PowerShell 3 script which would scan through `D:\folder` with bunch of sub folders to delete oldest file, file by file until free space is 5GB and stop then. Empty folders should remain as seems that the application what creates those files and folders, needs those empty folders.

I created a script like this, but I need to loop and modify it somehow, because it wants do delete sub-folders also with whole contents some times, but I need to delete file by by file in whatever folder the oldest file is until free space is 5GB:

```
[WMI]$part = "Win32_LogicalDisk.DeviceID='D:'"

if (($part.FreeSpace / $part.Size * 100) -lt 50) {
    foreach ($root in 'D:') {
        Get-ChildItem $root -Recurse |
            Sort-Object CreationTime |
            Select-Object -First 1 |
            Remove-Item
    }
}
```

Thanks you for your attention!

Comment: You're asking for 5GB to be the lower limit of your free space, but I don't see how your math supports that. I see 50%.

Comment: my actual partition is 3.5Tb so 5Gb free is 0.14% in my case

Comment: Right, but look at your math. `($part.FreeSpace / $part.Size * 100) -lt 50` will return true if your free space percentage is less than 50. You've asked for a way to free up 5GB.

Comment: I'm well aware of that. Lets assume I have 10Gb drive and i need to get 5gb free space then.

Answer (score 0):

Add `-File` (if you use PS 3.0), you will not get folders this way, only files. You can also use a `while` loop instead of `if` : while free space is under 50%, it will go on and delete files, one at a time. In this case, at the end, of the loop, you need to refresh the free space information.

I'm not sure if the WMI call has to be made *inside* the `while` loop too, to have the lastest information.

```
[WMI]$part = "Win32_LogicalDisk.DeviceID='D:'"
$percent = $part.FreeSpace / $part.Size * 100

while ($percent -lt 50) {
    Get-ChildItem "D:\" -Recurse -File |
        Sort-Object CreationTime |
        Select-Object -First 1 |
        Remove-Item
    $percent = $part.FreeSpace / $part.Size * 100
}
```

Using PS 2.0:

```
[WMI]$part = "Win32_LogicalDisk.DeviceID='D:'"
$percent = $part.FreeSpace / $part.Size * 100

while ($percent -lt 50) {
    Get-ChildItem "D:\" -Recurse |
        Where-Object { -not $_.PSisContainer } |
        Sort-Object CreationTime |
        Select-Object -First 1 |
        Remove-Item
    $percent = $part.FreeSpace / $part.Size * 100
}
```

Comment: This deleted all files on my test machine folders, most likely because WMI call is inside while loop. I will keep testing